# Change color of button in MVC using js

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to change the color of button on click (green) and if I am clicking to cancel button I want same color of button(blue)..I am using MVC .I have created a java script function for that button ..where I need to change..
this is my function

```
function addNewTransCode() {
    $('.trShow').removeClass("saveBg");
    $('.transHide').attr("style", 'display:none;');
    $('.transShow').attr("style", 'display:block;');

    $('#trAddTransCode').attr('style', 'display:table-row;');
}
```

this is my html code for that button --

```
  <a href="javascript:addNewTransCode() ;" class="btn btn-default pull-right marginright11" >+ New Transaction Code</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you.

HTML

```
<a id='yourButtonID' class="btn btn-default pull-right marginright11" >+ New Transaction Code</a>
```

CSS

```
 <style>
        .clicked {
            background: green !important;
        }

        .un-clicked {
            background: blue !important;
        }

    </style>
```

JQuery

```
<script>
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $('#yourButtonID').click( function() {
                if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('clicked');
                    $(this).addClass('un-clicked');
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('un-clicked').addClass('clicked');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: it changing my whole background .i want same thing for button only..nice approach i have never uses  in such a way..